# Disable anpersand escaping in RestEasy XML response

Tags: java, xml, escaping, resteasy, ampersand

I have a simple restful service that transforms a JAXB-anntotated beans to response XML using RestEasy.
The XML tags could contain escaped special characters (e.g. &#8211;). But RestEasy marshaller escapes ampersand symbols one more time and i get &amp;#8211; instead of &#8211; in the result XML.

How should I avoid the unnecessary ampersand escaping?

Comment: What tags are you referring to? How are they defined? You should give an ezample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been hunting this down and there's no way I can find to fine-tune the way RESTEasy escapes characters when it's writing out the response. I'm working on using an interceptor to prevent this encoding.

For reference, it happens at setEscape() in the stack when it encodes UTF-8 XML.

```
Encoded.setEscape(String, boolean) line: 107    
UTF8XmlOutput.doText(String, boolean) line: 315 
UTF8XmlOutput.text(String, boolean) line: 299   
XMLSerializer.leafElement(Name, String, String) line: 325   
RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(XMLSerializer, Name, String, String) line: 210    
RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$1.writeLeafElement(XMLSerializer, Name, Object, String) line: 209    
TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl<BeanT,ValueT>.writeLeafElement(XMLSerializer, Name, BeanT, String) line: 250 
SingleElementLeafProperty<BeanT>.serializeBody(BeanT, XMLSerializer, Object) line: 98   
ClassBeanInfoImpl<BeanT>.serializeBody(BeanT, XMLSerializer) line: 332  
XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Object, String, JaxBeanInfo, boolean) line: 699    
SingleElementNodeProperty<BeanT,ValueT>.serializeBody(BeanT, XMLSerializer, Object) line: 152   
ClassBeanInfoImpl<BeanT>.serializeBody(BeanT, XMLSerializer) line: 332  
XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Object, String) line: 593  
ClassBeanInfoImpl<BeanT>.serializeRoot(BeanT, XMLSerializer) line: 320  
XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Object) line: 494 
MarshallerImpl.write(Object, XmlOutput, Runnable) line: 315 
MarshallerImpl.marshal(Object, Result) line: 244    
MarshallerImpl(AbstractMarshallerImpl).marshal(Object, OutputStream) line: 75   
JAXBXmlRootElementProvider(AbstractJAXBProvider<T>).writeTo(T, Class<?>, Type, Annotation[], 
...
```